# Mobile Safari Date Picker Output Format

Tags: forms, mobile, datepicker, mobile-safari

Is it possible to format the output of the mobile safari date picker?  I need my date to be formatted as:

MM/DD/YYYY

However the mobile safari date picker is formatting the date as:

Month DD, YYYY

And submitting it as:

YYYY-MM-DD

Answer (score 0):

Try formatting like this

```
<input type="date" value"mm/dd/yyyy" />
```

Remember the most of the world uses day first anyways.

Comment: The format is out of my control, third party requirement.  Tried adding a value as suggested but the date is still formatted as Month DD, YYYY in the display.  Did some more digging and it appears the value being sent is YYYY-MM-DD.  Any other thoughts?